# Error: no such function: json_each in SQLite with JSON1 installed

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sqlite-json1, sqlite-browser

I've installed SQLite3 with JSON1 through brew:

```
brew install sqlite3 --with-json1 --with-fts5
```

Version:

```
3.15.2 2016-11-28 19:13:37 bbd85d235f7037c6a033a9690534391ffeacecc8
```

When running a query, some functions work fine, such as `json_extract`:

```
sqlite> SELECT json_extract(Body, '$.issue.fields.labels') FROM Event WHERE json_extract(Body, '$.issue.fields.labels') != '[]';

["foo","bar","baz"]
```

However, when I try to use `json_each` or `json_tree`, it fails:

```
sqlite> SELECT json_each(Body, '$.issue.fields.labels') FROM Event WHERE json_extract(Body, '$.issue.fields.labels') != '[]';

Error: no such function: json_each
```

The `Body` field in the `Event` table is a valid JSON string:

```
{"issue":{"fields":{"labels": ["foo","bar","baz"]}}}
```

And the `labels` value is an array.

I've read the documentation (and looked at the [json_each examples](https://sqlite.org/json1.html#examples_using_json_each_and_json_tree_)), searched the interwebs, but couldn't find any additional requirements to enable this.

What am I doing wrong, or: how do I reap the benefits from json_each/json_tree?

Comment: For anyone coming across this now, the sqlite formula now includes JSON1 and FTS so you don't need the flags. Current version of sqlite in there (running MacBook Pro 2019) is 3.32.3 2020-06-18.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `json_each` and `json_tree` are *table-valued functions* which means that they can only be used to fetch data on a virtual table that already exists in memory, not to query data directly from the database.

See: [The Virtual Table Mechanism Of SQLite](https://sqlite.org/vtab.html#tabfunc2)

> 2.1.2. Table-valued functions
>
> A virtual table that contains hidden columns can be used like a
>   table-valued function in the FROM clause of a SELECT statement. The
>   arguments to the table-valued function become constraints on the
>   HIDDEN columns of the virtual table.

When `SELECT json_each(Body, '$.issue.fields.labels') ...` sqlite3 can't find a function that matches with its definition of `SELECT` and results in the error you see.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, You can't use `json_each()` and `json_tree()` as a field in your query, they are [**table-valued functions**](https://sqlite.org/vtab.html#tabfunc2). You can only use them like tables.

Answer (score 1):

The docs on [json_each on sqlite.com](https://sqlite.com/json1.html#examples_using_json_each_and_json_tree_) are brief.

The following may help to better understand how to use json_each and other json functions.

Create a table `JsonTest`. The column `Reply` contains json values.

```sql
CREATE TABLE "JsonTest" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Reply" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
)
```

Insert some records into the table

```sql
INSERT INTO JsonTest (Reply) 
SELECT 
'{"id": 2, "status": "ok", "body": [{"Ftr": "Gears", "Val": "10"},{"Ftr": "Brake", "Val": "Disc-Brake"}]}' as REPLY
UNION SELECT '{"id": 4, "status": "ok",  "body": [{"Ftr": "Gears", "Val": "12"},{"Feature": "Brake", "Val": "Disc-Brake"}]}'
UNION SELECT 'Error'     
UNION SELECT '{"id": 1, "status": "nok", "body": "empty"}'   
UNION SELECT 'Error'     
UNION SELECT '{"id": 5, "status": "nok", "body": "empty"}'
UNION SELECT '{"id": 6, "status": "ok",  "body": [{"Ftr": "Gears", "Val": "21"},{"Ftr": "Brake", "Val": "V-Brake"}]}'
UNION SELECT '{"id": 8, "status": "ok",  "body": [{"Ftr": "Gears", "Val": "18"},{"Ftr": "Brake", "Val": "V-Brake"}]}';
```

As you can see the

- some rows only contain `Error` and are not valid json
- other rows have a valid json object the property `body` has either a value `empty` or a value of type array like this

```json
[
  {"Ftr": "Gears", "Val": "21"},
  {"Ftr": "Brake","Val": "V-Brake"}
]
```

If the column `Reply` would always have a valid json value like this `'{"id": 5, "status": "nok" ...}` we could query for json field status like this:

```
SELECT JsonTest.id, jsonEach.Value 
    FROM JsonTest,json_each(JsonTest.Reply, '$.status') as jsonEach
    WHERE JsonTest.Reply not like 'Error';
```

[image: sqlite json]

But since some rows / records are not valid json a subquery like this `(SELECT *, ...) as sq` combined with `json_each(Reply, ...)` can be used to filter all records with valid json `WHERE JSON_VALID(Reply)`.

```sql
SELECT subquery.RecordId, subquery.Reply_id, jsonEach.value 
FROM 
(
  SELECT *, Id as RecordId, json_extract(Reply, '$.id') as Reply_id 
  FROM JsonTest 
  WHERE JSON_VALID(Reply)  -- filter to get only valid json rows
  AND json_extract(Reply, '$.status') like "ok" 
  AND json_extract(Reply, '$.body[1].Val') like "V-Brake"
) as subquery, json_each(Reply, '$.body') as jsonEach;
```

In [sqlite-browser](/questions/tagged/sqlite-browser) this returns this result

[image: sqlite_json_each]